# Proper Scope placement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I've got a facade class, which performs SQL queries on other models. I wanted to use scopes, but I am having doubts about where to implement them, and if they are better than using just plain methods. I'm also concern about good programming practice.

**First, this are my models**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects 

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base   
  belongs_to :User
  has_many :tasks, :inverse_of => :project

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :project, :inverse_of => :tasks 
  has_many  :instances

class Instance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task
```

**Facade class:**

```
def Function1(param)
    @var = @user.instances.where("...", param).order(:start_time).group_by { |x| x.method}
end         
def Function2
    @var = @user.instances.where("...").first
end 
def Function3 
    @var = @user.projects.distinct
end
```

1) Should function 1 and 2 be on the User model, or in the instances'?

2) Should function3 be on the User model or in the projects'?

3) Could I for example write a 'distinct' scope  on projects, and a 'User distinct projects' scope which calls projects'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Should function 1 and 2 be on the User model, or in the instances'?

In the instances - you are restricting the scope of the instances that are returned

2) Should function3 be on the User model or in the projects'?

The project - likewise to above. The user is still the user, but you will be restricting which projects are returned, therefore it's a project scope

3) Could I for example write a 'distinct' scope on projects, and a 'User distinct projects' scope which calls projects'?

Yes, you can do both if you really want to - in practice, it's probably not worth doing the user `distinct_projects` scope unless you are likely to reuse the user `distinct_projects` scope again somewhere else (eg in another scope). It doesn't save you any typing ;)

Comment: Thanks, I removed '.first' from the scope generated by function2